# Average function google sheets

Tags: excel

i am trying to build an average-function in this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dPxOh1Ei5IPheUj1BPq2slN_I9BmYJMdd_SmkSDSjjk/edit?usp=sharing).

How can i get the average for merchant a in CW6 ([CW34+CW35+CW36]/3), without a reference to the cellnumber.

So i need in E12 the average of the "merchant a" in the range of C:E.

I tried with match,index,averageif.. but havent got a solution.

Comment: Why `r-googlesheets` tag? https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets

Comment: Title says google sheets, tag says excel, which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your match function is on the right lines (except that you need a zero to specify an exact match), then you need to add an INDEX function to get the correct row from C2:E4 and AVERAGE to get the average:-

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($C$2:$E$4,MATCH(A12,$A$2:$A$4,0),0))
```

[image]